# Compute the probability that the person does not have the disease. Please Check my work

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

A certain disease occurs in $36$ % of the population. A test for the disease is fairly accurate: it misclassifies people with the disease as healthy $10$ % of the time and reports that a healthy person is diseased just $7$% of the time. Suppose that a person tests positive for the disease. Compute the probability that the person does not have the disease. Round your answer to two decimal places.

My answer:

## $P$(Positive∣ Disease)= $(0.90*0.36)/(0.90*0.36+0.07-0.64)$

## =$0.324/0.3688$

## =$0.88$

Please check My work

Comment: The probability $Pr(\text{positive}\mid\text{diseased})$ is given in the problem statement as $1-0.1=0.9$.  The problem as written asks you to calculate $Pr(\text{healthy}\mid\text{positive})$.  Presumably you just wrote things in the wrong order there.  Your denominator appears incorrect.  Remember that $Pr(\text{pos})=Pr(\text{pos}\cap \text{diseased})+Pr(\text{pos}\cap \text{healthy})$

Comment: It appears that you used a minus sign in place of a multiplication sign, it appears that you calculated the complement of the value you were supposed to, and it also appears that you are using equals signs where you should be using approximation signs.  *Use equals signs ONLY for equality!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you computed $P(\text{Positive | Disease})$. The question asks for $P(\text{No disease | Positive})$.

We have

$$\begin{align*}
P(\text{No disease | Positive})
&=\frac{P(\text{No disease } \cap \text{ Positive})}{P(\text{Positive})}\\\\
&=\frac{0.64\cdot0.07}{0.64\cdot0.07+0.36\cdot0.9}\\\\
&\approx 0.1215
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 0):

well,I think that you have made some mistakes.
Let A＝"no disease" , B＝‘positive’
we need to derive P(A|B)
according to bayes,
it equals to 0.07*(1-0.36)/(0.07*(1-0.36)+0.36*0.9)＝0.12
Actually, I am also not so sure about that. So, you had better do it yourself again.